# Compare item with follower

Tags: diablo-iii

Everyone knows the awesome "Stats changed if equipped" tooltip when hovering an item in your inventory.

It is possible to enable such a comparison tooltip for items usable by your follower to see if it's an upgrade for him/her?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've looked for it myself, and sadly, there's no way to enable this at the moment.

Comment: This answer is not valid anymore.

Comment: The answer is out of date.

Answer (score 4):

In the past you couldn't do it. Currently there is a way to compare follower's items. At the moment follower's comparison shows only 3 main factors - damage, toughness, recovery.

Do the following.

1. Hire follower.
2. Open your equipment.
3. Place mouse cursor over an item that your follower could possibly equip.
4. You will see comparison for you as usual. Additionally, comparison for the follower is shown, next to his/her portrait in upper left corner of the screen; *only for items that the follower can equip*.
5. If you have follower inventory opened, comparison will be shown next to his/her currently equipped item.

Not the best solution in my opinion, but still better this than none. My desired solution would be to press some key combination (shift? alt? shit+alt? whatever) to get full comparison. Probably won't happen any time soon.

Comment: This is the correct answer.